# How to search special character in history expansion in bash or zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, history-expansion

Some characters such as `?`, `^`, `$` have special meaning in history expansion, can I search them in the `!string` or `!?string[?]` event ?.

The help says nothing about how to do it:

```
`!STRING'
     Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position in
     the history list starting with STRING.
```

**update**

It doesn't make sense to search special character with `!string`. `!?string[?]` works fine on `^`,`$`.

The remaining question is how to search `?` in `!?string[?]`

Comment: `!?$` works on bash with no escaping

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks, see update.